# MVC validating nested objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a complex model made by several fields and nested objects.

My goal is to validate nested object only if at least one property has a value

example

```
public class MyModel 
{ 
  public Submodel element; 
}

public class Submodel 
{
  [required] 
  public string attr1;

  [required] 
  public string attr2;
}
```

I have already made the client-side validation. but those fields are posted as empty and the server side validation still fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that if both properties are `null` then its valid, but if the user enters one property, then both must be provided in order to be valid?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the `[Required]` annotation on a property of your model, your model will not pass validation if that property is null (i.e. `ModelState.IsValid` will be false). If you want at least one of `attr1` or `attr2` to have value for the validation to pass, you can either have that defined in a custom annotation, or combine `ModelState.IsValid` with your own validation. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid || !YourValidationFunction(model, ModelState))
   {
     return View(Model);
   }
}

public bool YourValidationFunction(MyModel model, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
   if (model.submodel.attr1 == null && model.submodel.attr2 == null)
    {
        modelState.AddModelError("submodel.attr1", "only 1 attr can be null!");
        modelState.AddModelError("submodel.attr2", "only 1 attr can be null!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The parameter for `ModelStateDictionary` is there in case you want to have this function in a service class; you don't need it if both functions are in the controller.

Comment: _MVC will not validate if it's null_. Of course it will, that what the `RequiredAttribute` does. It validates the value is not `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: please read the whole sentence and in the context of the question before you downrate. You don't even realize you are sayin the same thing in my answer. In the question the OP has  `RequiredAttribute` on a property and it's not *passing* validation *because* the value is null. Maybe it's your English so let me explain: "does not validate" here means "does not pass validation".

Comment: The first line of your answer is wrong. If a property is decorated with the `[Required]` attribute it **will** validate (and `ModelState` will be invalid). If you change the wording of you answer I will remove the downvote.

Comment: No it's not. Because my first line means exactly what you try to say: "Model will not pass validation", `ModelState.IsValid` will be false. Do you think it's more understandable if I put it that way?

Comment: Well maybe you're right. Let's not allow any space for confusion - I revised my wording.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of validating your object to test whether one of your properties/fields has a value is to implement `IValidateableObject`:

```
public class SubModel : IValidateableObject
{
    public string attr1 {get;set;}
    public string attr2 {get;set}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (attr1 == null | attr2 == null) //or some other criteria
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Some validation message here");
        }
    }
}
```

And to use this, within your action method just use the standard `ModelState.IsValid` which will invoke the `Validate` within your `SubModel`.